# Wrong result when solving: "chance that two random cards differ in color and value?"

Tags: python, probability

I'm trying to build a simulation for this question:

> "There are 50 cards of 5 different colors. Each color has cards
> numbered between 1 to 10. You pick 2 cards at random. What is the
> probability that they are not of same color and also not of same
> number?"

(From [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/There-are-50-cards-of-5-different-colors-It-comprises-of-10-Red-cards-10-blue-cards-10-orange-cards-10-green-cards-and-QTN_1608513.htm))

I should have a result like "73%" but with my code I get (consistently) "72%" or "71.8%".

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

# Building a deck of 10 cards for each of the 5 colors 
cards = np.array([c+str(n) for c in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") for n in range(1, 11)])

def random_cards_differ():
"""Returns True if two random cards differ"""
    a, b = np.random.choice(cards, 2, replace=False)
    if a[0] != b[0] and a[1] != b[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

nb_success = 0
nb_tries = 100000

for i in range(nb_tries):
    if random_cards_differ():
        nb_success += 1

print(nb_success / nb_tries)
>>> 0.71892
```

Is this normal? Is there a mistake in my code or is it a "random gotcha" caused by some seed or something else?

Comment: your code seems fine, the theoretical result 73% is supposed to be accurately reached when `numtrials -> infinity`, so you get pretty good results. Try running whole simulation 100 times (so 100 * 100000 draws) and get average of 100 simulations this is better estimator

Comment: Well I ran a lot of simulations and got the same result. If I got 72% then 74% I would not suspect a problem, but consistently getting 71.8% instead of 73% seemed weird. Indeed, @bogovicj found the mistake in my code

Comment: Yeap, missed that detail. Good catch! In fact creating string tuples and comparing substrings is a bad idea, This is perfect candidate for tuples, if you encoded cards as tuples it would save you a lot of trouble

Comment: I agree 100%, I initially tried `np.array([(c, n) for ...])` but `np.random.choice` wanted 1D arrays, so I used a quick solution, that led to my bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your code:

```
cards = np.array([c+str(n) for c in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") for n in range(1, 11)])
```

will produce "A10" and "A1" among other values, and

```
if a[0] != b[0] and a[1] != b[1]:
```

will return `true` when `a=A10` and `b=A1`, for example. This is why you're probably *consistently underestimating* the number of differences.

An easy fix would be to use:

```
cards = np.array([c+str(n) for c in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") for n in range(0, 10)])
```

instead, which is more readable anyway.  But if I were doing this, I might use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Even after this fix it's normal to not always get exactly the theoretical value, but it's bad if there's a bias (i.e. consistent under- or over- estimation).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed I was not expecting the exact theoretical value, but getting the same precise result which was different from the expected result seemed off, thanks for noticing the bug!